# Visual Studio 2017 Extension Development

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

Hi I want to upgrade my extension to visual studio 2017 but I got `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationAttribute` error, but I have been already added this reference?I got this error in compile time. Is there any reference to be added or else? Any comment about that?

```
D:\Visual Studio 2017\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0.dll ,version :10.0.0.0
```

My Error is

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CreatePkgDef : error : ArgumentException: No Visual Studio registration attribute found in this assembly.           
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The assembly should contain an instance of the attribute 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationAttribute' defined in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0' version '10.0.0.0'  
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.CreatePkgDef.ProcessAssembly(String fileName, Hive hive, PkgDefContext context, Boolean register, RegistrationMode mode) in f:\dd\src\vssdk\VSIntegration\Tools\src\CreatePkgDef\CreatePkgDef.cs:line 303
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found the solution,I remove all references of Microsoft.VisualStudio.****,after than  I add my project a new vsix in visual studio 2017 that time I download all packages from nuget and my project is compile now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 7):

Add GeneratePkgDefFile as false like below in the csproj file

```
<GeneratePkgDefFile>false</GeneratePkgDefFile>
```

Comment: I am restructuring my Visual Studio Extension. The dll which used to be the package is now just a class library which is used by a new package. On "downgrading" the package to a simple class library, it continued to run CreatePkgDef. Adding this option to the project file fixed it for me.

Comment: Where in the .csproj file?

Comment: You can add it in the PropertyGroup tag