# Visual Studio Extension works while debugging but when I Install the VSIX it is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to make one VSIX plugin in C#. The plugin works fine in when I am in develop mode. But when I am trying to install the plugin i.e. by double clicking the VSIX, it is not working.
I have read some documents and some people ae saying to make it package and then do the installation. But when I am setting the "Generate .pkgdef file" option as "True", I am getting a errors like - "CreatePkgDef : error : ArgumentException: No Visual Studio registration attribute found in this assembly." and The assembly should contain an instance of the attribute 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.RegistrationAttribute' defined in assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Framework' version '16.0.0.0'

Basically I want to deploy my VSIX. How can I do this ?Can someone help in this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Try to refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555049/visual-studio-2017-extension-development/47594645).

Comment: What sort of extension are you building/running?

A .VSIX  typically deploys a VSSDK package (with a .pkgdef), or a MEF based editor extension, or a project or item template. If you want a good answer, you'll need to provide a lot more detail as to what exactly you are doing, and maybe include a copy of your .vsixmanifest. From the sounds of it, you are not creating a VSSDK package, as you have no attributes that would allow the build to generate a .pkgdef file.

Comment: Hi @EdDore,
 I am using MEF based editor extension. Please have the manifest below.

  Please find the git hub [link](https://github.com/ramsankar184/TeamExplorerExtensionSample)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the real issue. Actually I am using ITeamExplorerNavigationItem2 to add a button in the Team Explorer.
I am using the property public System.Drawing.Image Image to control the button Icon.

```
public System.Drawing.Image Image => null // Button comes up  without any button icon

public System.Drawing.Image Image => System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("MyImage.png"); // button does not show up in the team explorer
```

What I am suspecting is, during debug it is finding the path of the "MyImage.png" but at run time the Image is not packaged to the VSIX, so it is not finding the .png path and subsequently it is not displaying the icon and button.

**To fix this issue**, I actually added a **Resource.resx** file to the project and added the Image inside that. Since the resource.resx file is added to VSIX file during compile time it is displayed correctly after installation.
The modified code

```
public System.Drawing.Image Image => Resource.MyImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

The assets that your VSIX installs are declared in the .vsixmanifest file.  In your case, you already have:

```
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%|" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="%CurrentProject%" Path="|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|" />
  </Assets>
```

However, the second item should be unnecessary.  Pkgdef files are needed only when registering a new package - i.e. a class that inherits from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package or Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage (these are used for different extensibility points than what you're using).  Since your MEF component is already registered (and that seems to be the only thing you need), your VSIX should already be able to install fine.

To give a little more detail about these, when the VSIX is installed, it will look at these assets and then reconfigure VS based on them.

- MefComponent means that this assembly should be added to Visual Studio's MEF catalog, which will then discover any exported parts appropriately.  I don't see you actually exporting anything, so there may be something missing there.  You might also need to add `[Export(typeof(ITeamExplorerNavigationItem))]` to your class (but I'm not familiar with that feature, so I'm not positive).
- VsPackage will take a bunch of registration attributes and convert them to registry keys (this actually is what the .pkgdef file contains).  Upon installation, those will be merged into Visual Studio's registry hive.

Edit (reply to comment):
If the issue is that your image isn't loading, it's probably because either your VSIX doesn't contain your image, or because you're not using the correct file path.  By default, all file paths will be resolved relative to the folder where devenv.exe resides.  Assuming your image is located next to your DLL, you probably need to do something like this:

```
string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string iconPath = Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "MyImage.png");
```

You can use a tool like Process Monitor ([procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)) to see exactly which path the process is failing to load.  (I don't know why it would work when debugging but not when installing.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The second item I added to check whether it might work. Even without that also it is not working. My point is how is it working while debugging both in release and debug mode but when I am installing it is not working. What I came to know - I am using public 
System.Drawing.Image Image => System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("MyImage.png"); which does not work after installation (may be the resources file is not added to VSIX). If I make it public System.Drawing.Image Image => null then it works without any button image.

Comment: @rsgeeks184 I extended my answer to reply to this new information.